# Praxis BB convertor into 2018 Supersix Evo

Tags: bottom-bracket, cannondale, creak

Just wondering if anyone had fitted a M30 praxis BB into a 2018 supersix evo, was just wondering how you go on with the internal cable for the front mech and the rear derailleur that seem to enter near the bottom bracket, do they get in the way?

Also with regarding the required tools can I get away with just using two bottom bracket wrenches that fit onto Hollowtech II BB's for tightening the cups or do I need to use thier M30 BB tool with 2 socket wrenches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you shouldn't have to touch the cables to change the bottom bracket.

I have used the M30 Praxis BB30 (not your PF30, but similar) without issues.

Your current bottom bracket shouldn't have issues with the cables and neither should the new one.

The hollowtech tool won't fit. You have to get their tool.

As a cheap alternative, you could use mold grips, but this risks damaging the cups, and frankly, it's not worth it.

If you're not 100% confident, you should take it to a bike shop, you don't have as much room for effor with pressfit bottom brackets, in terms or damaging the frame, incorrect bonding and misalignment.

Comment: You mean [*mole* grips (UK term) or vice grips (US term)](https://www.google.com/search?q=Mole+grips&tbm=isch). Don't put those things anywhere near a bike.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I mean, technically, they do the job. I recommeneded the tool... but...

Comment: ok thanks looks like I'm going to have to buy a couple of socket wrenches then as well :-(